# Is there a way to disable opening a new window in GStreamer for videos?

Tags: gstreamer, glib, vala

I am making an app with gtk. I need a way to play only the audio of a, say, mp4 file.

```
var player = Gst.ElementFactory.make("playbin", "play");
player.uri = "http://ks4.imslp.info/files/imglnks/usimg/e/ea/IMSLP478767-PMLP776231-Plas_yn_Rhiw.mp4";
player.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING);
```

I want only the audio to play; I don't want GStreamer to open a window to display the video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the `flags` property of `playbin`:

```
  flags               : Flags to control behaviour
                        flags: readable, writable
                        Flags "GstPlayFlags" Default: 0x00000617, "soft-colorbalance+deinterlace+soft-volume+text+audio+video"
                           (0x00000001): video            - Render the video stream
                           (0x00000002): audio            - Render the audio stream
                           (0x00000004): text             - Render subtitles
                           (0x00000008): vis              - Render visualisation when no video is present
                           (0x00000010): soft-volume      - Use software volume
                           (0x00000020): native-audio     - Only use native audio formats
                           (0x00000040): native-video     - Only use native video formats
                           (0x00000080): download         - Attempt progressive download buffering
                           (0x00000100): buffering        - Buffer demuxed/parsed data
                           (0x00000200): deinterlace      - Deinterlace video if necessary
                           (0x00000400): soft-colorbalance - Use software color balance
                           (0x00000800): force-filters    - Force audio/video filter(s) to be applied
```

So when you select a flag combination that excludes the `video` it should not render the video path.